# Android SQLite update items with whereclause

Tags: android, database, sqlite, filtering

I need some suggestions about how to update data in SQLite database. Now I am doing it in this way:

```
public void insertadoMedidasAdoptarCorrectamente(String codMedAdC,
        String codigoServicio) {
    AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelper = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelper
            .getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.insertadoCorrectamente, 1);

    sqliteDatabase.update("MedidasAdoptarSeleccionadas", contentValues,
            "codigomedida = '" + codMedAdC + "' AND codigoservicio = '"
                    + codigoServicio + "'", null);

    sqliteDatabase.close();
}
```

I heard that this is not the best way to update data. I think that sometimes it faults. Because of that code:

```
sqliteDatabase.update("MedidasAdoptarSeleccionadas", contentValues,
            "codigomedida = '" + codMedAdC + "' AND codigoservicio = '"
                    + codigoServicio + "'", null);

    sqliteDatabase.close();
```

You can observe that I am filtering items by two fields. I have seen that this could be done with whereclause arguments.

So, my question is, which is the best way to filter data that is gonna to update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do `"codigomedida = '" + codMedAdC + "'` since that will break if there is a `'` in `codMedAdC`.

But doing it like

```
String[] whereArgs = { codMedAdC, codigoServicio };
sqliteDatabase.update("MedidasAdoptarSeleccionadas", contentValues,
            "codigomedida = ? AND codigoservicio = ?", whereArgs);
```

is fine.

You could think about keeping the database open if you do those updates regularly. Creating new `AndroidOpenDbHelper` and opening the database each time takes some time.